# PHP: set a global variable in a class

Tags: php, class, variables, global-variables

In a PHP class, is there a way to set set a global variable that doesn't need to be called in each function?

For example, I have a variable called `$settings` which contains an array of values:

```
Array( [option_1] => on, [option_2] => on, [option_3] => off )
```

The `get_option()` function comes from WordPress. The values in the `$settings` array determine which functions to run:

```
class My_Class {

    public function __construct() {
        # Get array of options
        $settings = get_option( 'my_options' );

        if ( is_array( $settings ) || is_object( $settings ) ) {
            if ( $settings['option_1'] == 'on' ) {
                add_action( 'tag_1', array( $this, 'function_1' ) );
            }

            if ( $settings['option_2'] == 'on' ) {
                add_action( 'tag_2', array( $this, 'function_2' ) );
            }
        }
    }

    public function function_1() {
        # Call the array of options again
        $settings = get_option( 'my_options' );

        echo 'This option is ' . $settings['option_1'];
    }

    public function function_2() {
        # Code here...
    }

new My_Class();
```

However, I call the following line twice in my `__construct()` and  `function_1()`:

```
$settings = get_option( 'my_options' );
```

Instead of calling this variable twice in two different functions, what's the proper way of calling the same variable which can be used within different functions of my class? I tried adding the `$settings` variable function just below the `class My_Class`, but that didn't work:

```
class My_Class {

    global $settings = get_option( 'my_options' );
    # Rest of the code below...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare $settings as a class property

```
protected $settings;
```

Then inside `__construct`

```
$this->settings = get_option( 'my_options' );
```

You can then access it anywhere inside the class using `$this->settings`

```
public function function_1() {
    echo 'This option is ' . $this->settings['option_1'];
}
```

For more details about `properties`, you can refer to PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php